# Bootstrap's justify-content and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

I have the following h1 with container. I want this h1 to be centered horizontally inside of this container. Since I use bootstrap I used `.d-flex` and `.justify-content-center`, which works fine - but apparently not for  Internet Explorer.

```
<div class="coverflow-image-title-container d-flex justify-content-center">
    <h1 class="coverflow-image-title">Title</h1>   
</div>
```

```
.coverflow-image-title-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.coverflow-image-title {
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  font-family: "NBI Regular";
  position: absolute;
  transition: font-size 1s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

How do I realize the same behavior, but for Internet Explorer?

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: @j08691 It's IE 11

Comment: I think you need to specify a `flex-direction` for flexboxes in IE.

Comment: @MattHamer5 What direction did you think of?

Comment: this should be the reference point: https://caniuse.com/#search=justify-content

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this sample code:

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <h2>Justify content</h2>
  <p>Use the .justify-content-* classes to change the alignment of flex items. Choose from start (default), end, center, between or around:</p>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-start bg-secondary mb-3">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-primary">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end bg-secondary mb-3">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-primary">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center bg-secondary mb-3">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-primary">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bg-secondary mb-3">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-primary">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around bg-secondary mb-3">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-primary">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output in IE browser as below:

[image]

More detail information about using Bootstrap 4 .justify-content-* classes, please check [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp).